# Extracting SMS data from a XML

Tags: awk, csv, xml, sms

I have a large xml file of my SMS messages. I want to put them into an easily accessible csv format. I've been trying to extract the 'address', 'messageBody' and 'messageTime' sections specifically but with no luck.

```
<messageType>1</messageType><messageTime>1624297248761</messageTime><read>null</read><status>null</status><service_center>null</service_center><person>null</person><seen>1</seen></chat><chat><threadID>50</threadID><address>447917504050</address><messageBody>Yeah mate let's do lunch and catch up.</messageBody><messageType>1</messageType><messageTime>1629944007697</messageTime><read>null</read><status>null</status><service_center>null</service_center><person>null</person><seen>1</seen></chat><chat><threadID>50</threadID><address>447917563330</address><messageBody>You going now mate</messageBody>
```

I've had minor success with:

`cat SMS.xml | awk -F'address' '{print $2}'`

But this only takes the first 'address' from the line, ignoring the others.

Any ideas on how to get this data in to a readable csv format?

Any help interpretting the number in the 'messageTime' section would be greatly appreciated too.

EDIT: The actual xml file does have balanced open and close tags and is formatted properly. I have just included a small excerpt here.

Comment: Well, you *could* do the obvious thing and use a tool or library specifically designed to handle XML.. Yes, XML's designers recognized that sometimes the "desperate AWK programmer" would try to pull the data out without a proper tool, but that is really not the right solution.

Comment: The XML that you show have unbalanced open and close tags, and no root tag. This makes it very difficult to parse with any XML parser. Could you possibly update it so that it is well formed?

Comment: If it isn't balanced, it isn't XML. Fix that first. ..  Also, I misremembered the quote, it should be "desperate PERL hacker", abbreviated to DPH.

Comment: Please edit your xml, it's a wrong xml file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the XML is well formed and that all the `chat` node occurs under some single `root` node, then you may possibly use `xq` (part of the distribution of `yq`, from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```bash
xq -r '["address","messageBody","messageTime"], (.root.chat[] | [.address,.messageBody,.messageTime]) | @csv' file.xml
```

Correcting your broken XML in the question by adding missing start and end tags, this would produce the following CSV output:

```
"address","messageBody","messageTime"
,,"1624297248761"
"447917504050","Yeah mate let's do lunch and catch up.","1629944007697"
"447917563330","You going now mate",
```

Comment: For the sake of giving a complete answer you could tag on a post-processing step to format the date-time stamp in a way similar to what @GlennJackman does, eg. with the added pipe: `... |  TZ=UTC awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} /"[0-9]{13}"/ {$NF = strftime("%F %T", substr($NF,2,length($NF)-1) / 1000)} 1'`. That yields a human readable date-time, only if the date-time stamps are correctly formed with 13 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Another [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) answer that outputs comma-separated data:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //chat -v messageTime -o , -v address -o , -v messageBody -n file.xml
```

```
1624297248761,,
1629944007697,447917504050,Yeah mate let's do lunch and catch up.
,447917563330,You going now mate
```

This is putting the message body *last* so that comma-separated data would take the 3rd field to the end as the body.

The message time is milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. One way to process it, with GNU awk:

```bash
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //chat -v messageTime -o , -v address -o , -v messageBody -n file.xml \
| TZ=UTC gawk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} {$1 = strftime("%F %T", $1 / 1000)} 1'
```

outputs

```
2021-06-21 17:40:48,,
2021-08-26 02:13:27,447917504050,Yeah mate let's do lunch and catch up.
1970-01-01 00:00:00,447917563330,You going now mate
```

This format makes it easy to sort chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

Since the XML is not proper as mentioned in the comments, wrap all the text in a new tag like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myxml>
  <chat>
  ....your data which already includes </chat><chat> 
  </chat>
</myxml>
```

then you can use `xmlstarlet` like this (ex. to get the address):

`xmlstarlet select --template --value-of /myxml/chat/address --nl input_file.xml`

(`input_file.xml` should contain the data with the extra tags as described above)

more examples [here](https://opensource.com/article/21/7/parse-xml-linux)

Comment: Are you suggesting parsing the document once per variable?

Comment: In the example I provided yes that was the case. I am not really familiar with `xmlstarlet` (just found it now to answer this question) but from the examples I linked it might be possible to get more values at once

Comment: BUT I believe that the `xq` solution you mentioned is a lot more elegant :)

Comment: I started out with `xmlstarlet` too, but when I realised that the message text might be free text (including commas and newlines), I wanted something that does proper CSV quoting.